# I don't understand why this code isn't performing properly

Tags: c++

```
/* Program Name: BadDate.cpp 
Function: This program determines if a date entered by the user is valid.  
Input:  Interactive
Output: Valid date is printed or user is alerted that an invalid date was entered
*/  

#include <iostream>
bool validateDate(int, int, int);
using namespace std;
 int main()
{ 
  // Declare variables

  int year;
  int month;
  int day;
  const int MIN_YEAR = 0, MIN_MONTH = 1, MAX_MONTH = 12, MIN_DAY = 1, MAX_DAY = 31; 
  bool validDate = true;
```

This is the work of the housekeeping() method
   Get the year, then the month, then the day

```
int housekeeping() {
  cout << "Please enter a year: "<< endl;
  cin >> year;
  cout << "Please enter a month: "<< endl;
  cin >> month;
  cout << "Please enter a day: "<< endl;
  cin >> day;
}
```

This is the work of the detailLoop() method
   Check to be sure date is valid

```
int detailLoop() {
  if(year <= MIN_YEAR)  // invalid year
    validDate = false;
  else if (month < MIN_MONTH || month > MAX_MONTH)  // invalid month
    validDate = false;
  else if (day < MIN_DAY || day > MAX_DAY) // invalid day
    validDate = false; 
}
```

This is the work of the endOfJob() method
   test to see if date is valid and output date and whether it is valid or not

```
int endOfJob() 
{
  if(validDate == true)
  { 
     // Output statement
     cout << " Your date is valid!"<< endl;
  }
  else
  {
     // Output statement
     cout << " Your date is not valid!"<< endl;
  }
}   
} // end of main() function
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. And what exactly is your question? What is your code doing that you do not expect it to do?

Comment: it is supposed to get input from the user and determine whether or not the date provided is a valid date or not

Comment: And? When you run it what happens? You haven't provided us any information.

Comment: Your variables seem to be local to the `main` function, and no references are passed to the functions that populate them, nor is anything returned. Your functions aren't called by anything. What on Earth are you expecting?

Comment: Don't create functions inside of functions.

Comment: Isn't working properly is a poor and vague statement of the issue. Aren't all the questions posted here weren't working properly? You need to provide the desired output and the actual output.

Comment: Why do u have to define functions inside main ?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work at all, let alone working _properly_. Apart of that, it doesn't seem to be going to print what you said: the comment states it outputs a valid date, while the code seems to print the `" Your date is valid!"` message instead of a date. Additionally your code apparently is meant to accept `2017 02 30` although it  certainly isn't a valid date.